IIS Express forces all applications to use the first application's application pool
I'm trying to run two applications on the one site, in IIS Express. The relevant part of my applicationhost.config shows them both configured to use different application pools:
<site name="Example" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="ParentAppPool" preloadEnabled="true">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Path\To\ParentApp" />
  </application>
  <application path="/child" applicationPool="ChildAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Path\To\ChildApp" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.example.com" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:dev.example.com" />
  </bindings>
</site>

The "parent" app works fine, but on browsing to /child, I get a 500.35 error:

ASP.NET Core does not support multiple apps in the same app pool


Only one in-process application is allowed per IIS application pool. Please assign the application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/child' to a different IIS application pool.

Both apps are set to use different app pools, and nothing else is using either of these app pools.
If I enable traceFailedRequestsLogging, then the log files show that requests going to https://dev.example.com:443/ and those going to https://dev.example.com:443/child/ are using the same processId, and both are recorded as using the first application's app pool: appPoolId="ParentAppPool"
Both of these app pools are specified in applicationhost.config:
<add name="ParentAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" autoStart="true" />
<add name="ChildAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" autoStart="true" />

If I change the parent app to specify an undefined app pool, I get an error about a catastrophic failure.
If I instead change the child app to specify an undefined app pool, I don't get this error, and things behave the same as before.
This leads me to the conclusion that all applications under a site are forced by IIS Express to use the same app pool, even though this causes them to fail.
Is there a way to work around this?

What you observed is by design and has been well known for more than a decade. No workaround but to switch to full IIS.

Thanks for that. Although the linked question's answer contains this information, which is directly relevant to answering my question, I don't believe it makes sense to count them as duplicate questions.
